# Why does Visual Studio spins up HDD it doesn't use?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, startup

This is something that is bothering me quite a bit, because it slows down VS start up and add to system noise. I have a Western Digital drive that goes to sleep when not in use. This drive is for data only, Visual Studio or any of its components were never installed on it. No files VS solutions use (including source/project files) were ever on that drive. So Visual Studio should not try to access it. But every time I start VS, it causes that drive to spin up. Why does it do that and how can I stop it? This happens in both VS 2008 and 2010, but I'm most concerned with 2010 right now.

**Update:** Alright, just promoting some new information from comments and updating the intended question.

The reason it spins up the drive is that it queries all drives for available space. Is there a setting for this somewhere? It sure doesn't look like the usual config dialog has it.

Also, for people voting to close. Why would SO have Visual Studio tags (so popular too) if we aren't allowed to ask VS questions?

Comment: Run procmon to see what files it's accessing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The reason appears to be quite stupid. It appears it just wants to see how much space is available on that drive. It shouldn't query drives it doesn't use. I sure hope there is a setting for this somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would do that.  It may be looking for a drive with the most free space for temp files.